# Updating Values as Zero from Excel Import

Tags: php

I am using the followng code, to import csv into mysql.

```php
 if($_POST['sform'] == "1")
{
     $fname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];        
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);        
     if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
     { 
        $filename = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
              {
                $row++;
                $data_entries[] = $data ;
              }
              fclose($handle);
         }
         foreach($data_entries as $line)
         {
              $sql = "INSERT into testposts(ID,UID,title,tags,desc) values('','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
$conn->execute($sql);
          $conn->execute($line);
         }
         $msg = "Successfully Imported";
     }
     else
     {
         $error = "Invalid File";
     }   
}
```

When I try to update then all values gets updated as 0

my csv file as follow (example)

```
1,title,tags,send2
```

Am not including PID value as it is auto incremented

So I tried with my second variation

```
if($_POST['sform'] == "1")
{
     $fname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];        
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);        
     if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
     { 
 $filename = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
              $sql = "INSERT into testposts(ID,UID,title,tags,desc) values('','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
          mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
          //$conn->execute($sql);
         }
         $msg = "Successfully Imported";
     }
     else
     {
         $error = "Invalid File";
     }   
}
```

In my second code, it uploads the value correctly as expected but it inserts twice.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the second version works:

```
$sql = "INSERT into testposts(ID,UID,title,tags,desc) values('','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";
```

You have more values than column names. Is there a `$data[4]`?

If you have warnings enabled, your data could consist of php warnings and these warnings could contain `'` characters, breaking your query.

You should really switch to PDO / prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems and errors like these ones.

Comment: sorry, it is till ('','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]'), some how, i did not delete it when i modified the original content before pasting it here

Comment: I played with the looping on the first one and it worked, it did not insert twice as well as posted exactly as required. sql injection has been taken care and thanks for your advice and help.